# CellValueChanging event does not fire on first change

Tags: c#, events, gridview, devexpress

i have set a CellValueChanging event for devexpress grid view cell in which by changing the value of a cell (which is combobox) the value of other cells changes.
when the one of the items is selected, the cell value changing event fires but noting is shows in the other cells but when another combobox item is selected it works very good.
this also occur for each new row.
how can i handle this?
this is the event:

```
private void windowBasedMainGridView_CellValueChanging(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if the selected column is not int or dbl, set the descritazation to be automatic
        if (e.Column.FieldName == "CriterionParameter")
        {
            windowBasedMainGridView.SetFocusedRowCellValue("CriterionParameterDiscretization", "Automatic");
            string strSelectedColumnName = commonlyUsedMethodsClass.ColumnNameFromColumnCaption(frmMainForm.projectDataSet.Tables[strinputDatatableName], e.Value.ToString());
            Type typeOfSelectedParameter = frmMainForm.projectDataSet.Tables[strinputDatatableName].Columns[strSelectedColumnName].DataType;
            if ((typeOfSelectedParameter == typeof(double) || typeOfSelectedParameter == typeof(int)))
            {
                windowBasedMainGridView.SetFocusedRowCellValue("CriterionParameterDesceretazationMethod", "Linear");
                //set the min and max of property
                if (typeOfSelectedParameter == typeof(double))
                {
                    List<double> valuesList = commonlyUsedMethodsClass.DoubleListGenerator(frmMainForm.projectDataSet.Tables[strinputDatatableName], strSelectedColumnName);
                    windowBasedMainGridView.SetFocusedRowCellValue("CriterionParameterMinimum", valuesList.Min());
                    windowBasedMainGridView.SetFocusedRowCellValue("CriterionParameterMaximum", valuesList.Max());
                }
                else
                {
                    List<int> valuesList = commonlyUsedMethodsClass.IntegerListGenerator(frmMainForm.projectDataSet.Tables[strinputDatatableName], strSelectedColumnName);
                    windowBasedMainGridView.SetFocusedRowCellValue("CriterionParameterMinimum", valuesList.Min());
                    windowBasedMainGridView.SetFocusedRowCellValue("CriterionParameterMaximum", valuesList.Max());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                windowBasedMainGridView.SetFocusedRowCellValue("CriterionParameterDesceretazationMethod", "");
                windowBasedMainGridView.SetFocusedRowCellValue("CriterionParameterMinimum", null);
                windowBasedMainGridView.SetFocusedRowCellValue("CriterionParameterMaximum", null);
            }


        }
```

the picture below show that the item is selected first(the other cells does not fill automatically):
[image]
the below picture is when first select another item of combo box and then select the depth item(other cells are filled automatically based on cellvaluechanging event):
[image]

Comment: Show us the code in the cellchanging event please.

Comment: i added the code in the question

Comment: Wow.. That is a lot of code. Do you reallize that every time you call SetFocusedRowCellValue you end up back in this event handler?

Comment: this all code does only work for changing the value of 2 cells to change the value of other cells based on them.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this method at the end of your handler:

```
windowBasedMainGridView.BeginDataUpdate();
windowBasedMainGridView.EndDataUpdate();
```

OR:

```
windowBasedMainGridView.RefreshData();
```

Also, you may need call [PostEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_PostEditortopic) method:

```
windowBasedMainGridView.PostEditor();
```